# python replace \\ with \ in stringpath automatically

Tags: python-3.x

how can I replace `"\"` in path string with `"\\"` python, u know `\` is for escape character and `r'\'` and `r"\"` also don't work, neither in `str.replace()` or in `re.sub()`

Comment: If the string is a directory path, using raw string should work. can u give an example, what is the error you are facing ..?

Comment: You shouldn't even bother yourself with this. Use [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and let it do all the work for you

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to get the correct path you can use the raw string:

```
r"C:\Users"
# will return
Out[2]: 'C:\\Users'
# in the console

#however if you print it, it will print this:
print(r"C:\Users")
C:\Users
```

if you want to combine parts of the path dynamically i recommend the os library (standard library)

use it like this:

```
import os
path = os.path.join(r"first_part_of_path", r"other_part_of_path", "filename.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

from python's documentation: "The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in a string literal prefixed with 'r'. So r"\n" is a two-character string containing '' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python code using this raw string notation."

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

below maybe what you are looking for:

x=r'this, is a \test'
re.subn('\\','\\',x)

Answer (score 0):

from the standard library, you could use *[os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath)*

Example:

```
import os
myDir = r"path\to\dir"
normalized = os.path.normpath(myDir)
```

Which enables the following :

```
>>> normalized
'path\\to\\dir'

>>> print(normalized)
path\to\dir

>>> str(normalized)
'path\\to\\dir'

>>> repr(normalized)
"'path\\\\to\\\\dir'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized our path for i.e.

```
path_str="E:\neural network\Pytorch"
```

can be changed to

```
path_str=path_str.encode('unicode-escape').decode().replace('\\\\', '\\')
```

and this would also do it automatically without need to manipulating the string manually to

```
path_str=r"E:\neural network\Pytorch"
```